# List out the Third Party Speech Recognition SDK or Library

Tags: sdk, speech-recognition, speech

I am developing Speech Recognition application (Audio to Text Conversion) in using C#.Net.

I have tried with Microsoft SAPI 5.1 the accuracy to bad.

Now i would like to go for any other third party software which would fulfill my requirement.

Nuance Dragon Naturally Speaking SDK is available in Market, but they didn't provide the trial version at least two days, because i would like to integrate with my application.

Please provide if you people already have an experience on this scenario.

Comment: For telephone speech there is not much choice, you can only try [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)

Comment: What exactly *are* your requirements?

Comment: I want to Convert Audio(recorded audio file) to Text format using C#.net, so i am looking is there any third party speech recognition engine which provides 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are still unclear but on the surface your request for 100% accuracy would seem unreachable. You say you wish to convert audio to text so assuming that audio is some type of conversation, you are looking at a Statistical Language Model (SLM) based solution. 100% accuracy for SLM is highly unlikely. If your audio is from a known and tightly constrained domain you may get close to 100%.

I would suggest that you provide more detail so that your question may be answered more specifically. Information that would be useful

1. What is the subject matter of the audio? Specifically are you trying to transcribe free speech or is it more constrained?
2. Single or Multi Speaker?
3. Language?
4. Audio quality?

It is fairly simple to suggest a list of speech recognition companies but this would be of little use as not all companies address the same applications.

Comment: The Subject Matter of the audio : conversation with IVR (It could be like free speech because i don't want to be tightly coupled with one audio it should recognize any IVR conversation)

Single or Multi Speaker: Multi Speaker

Language : English

Audio Quality : Min quality is 8000KHz,16Bit/8Bit,Mono/Stereo max it can be anything.